# Best solution for exporting Word documents to PDF programatically (without using a "software printer")?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, office-2007, office-interop

I'm looking for a way to export a Word document as a PDF. I would like to do this without the use of a "software printer" (such as CutePDF, etc.) and stick to reference assemblies if at all possible. I'm using Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies to generate a Word Document which I save to a temporary directory. So its not necessary for this solution to interact directly with Microsoft Office, unless it needs to.

Comment: Are you generating this Word doc from another Word doc?

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 2007 has a built-in (or add-on) converter to PDF, therefore you can save office 2007 files to PDF without much hassle.

Otherwise, you'll have to use some sort of conversion assembly (there should be commercial assebmlies that perfrom this task), or a converstion application that can receive command-line arguments, or maybe even some web-based service for office-to-pdf conversion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an add-on, but it is freely available from the Office Download site.

Comment: -1: since the OP is using ASP.NET, and Office Interop does not reliably work in a server application.